# Django turn based browser game - database design to handle separate time steps

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm developing a turn-based strategy browser game with Python/Django.
The idea is this: Players interact with the website during turn n. They watch their game state (the game "world") and issue orders that are to be executed in the next time step evaluation.
At some point int time, the website gets frozen and the turn engine calculates the new game status for time step n+1 from status at timestep n plus the the list of orders of all players.
During this time step evaluation, i need to read the state of objects from time step n and create/write objects at timestep n+1.
How to implement this the most effective way? (It is a question about the design of the database)

I have considered the following options:
The first approach would be this:
Have each world object carry a timestep parameter. 
It will probably be very cumbersome to always filter on time step. Also, the database will grow with each timestep as it will contain the entire history since timestep 0.

The second approach would be this:
Have different physically disjoint databases for each time step.
That is, during time step evolution, create a new database for timestep n+1. During evaluation, work on the databases (n, n+1) concurrently. Once time step evaluation is finished, delete (or better: archive) database of timestep n and replace it with database n+1. (This will have the nice side-effect of having a database snapshot of each timestep as a backup)
The latter seems to be the better approach to me. But i need some advice on how to work on two databases at once.

Are there any other advice you can give me to make a choice.
Do you see any other possible approaches?
Are there any third-party libraries or Django -plugins dealing with similar issues?
If i would use the second approach, how can i tell Django to use 2 databases at once, with same type of objects in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have it mostly figured out. Two databases, `default` and `future`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'default',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    },
    'future': {
        'NAME': 'future',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    },
}
```

Write your views/whatever normally using models as usual. These will be written to the `default`database as you are probably used to.

---

Create a management command which updates the game state... (You could also throw this code into a Celery task or something else, but for this answer I plan to invoke via command-line using cron scheduler.)

```
# project/app/management/commands/run_turn.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import subprocess
from optparse import make_option

def copy_default_to_future():
    # Copy database before acting on game state
    # use the subprocess library for bash execution of mysql/postgres commands

    # ...

def copy_future_to_default():
    # Copy database after acting on game state
    # use the subprocess library for bash execution of mysql/postgres commands

    # ...

def upload_backup_to_cloud():
    # i recommend using django-cumulus and a custom backups storage container

    # ...

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<attachment_path attachment_path ...>'
    help = 'Processes game state at end of turn'

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('-u', '--upload-backup',
            action='store_true',
            dest='upload',
            default=False,
            help='Upload database export to cloud object storage'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
         if options.get('upload', None):
             upload_backup_to_cloud()

         copy_default_to_future()

         # ... change your gamestate
         for player in Player.objects.using('future').all():
             player.increment()
         # ...

         copy_future_to_default()

         print "Game state updated."
```

---

`patrick@lucca:~$ crontab -e`

```
@hourly /home/patrick/.virtualenvs/browsergame/bin/python /path/to/project/manage.py run_turn --upload-backup
```

References:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about the `using` function. Will have a deeper look into it.